# Polynomial identity in positive terms, including AM-GM bound

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Consider $n$ nonnegative numbers $x_1 \cdots x_n$. An easy  consequence of the AM-GM inequality
$$
\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n} 
$$
is a lower bound on a polynomial
$$
(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n)^n \geq n^n (x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)
$$
which holds with equality iff $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n$.

Question 1 (existence):
Can one write the LHS polynomial as an identity which is a sum of only nonnegative terms, including the RHS? These terms can again be composites (other than the considered difference LHS - RHS itself), if it can be guaranteed that they are nonnegative.

Question 2 ($n=4$):
What's a formula for $n=4$?

Question 3 (general $n$):
Is there a principle for composing a formula for general $n$?

**First solutions / remarks:**

Here are ways of doing that for $n=2$:
$$
(x + y)^2 =  4 x  y + (x - y)^2
$$
and $n=3$:
$$
(x+y+z)^3 = 27 x y z + (x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3 x y z) + 3 (z-y)^2 x + 3 (x-z)^2 y+ 3 (y-x)^2 z
$$
where the second term (in brackets) is nonnegative again by AM-GM:  $ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \geq  3 \sqrt[3]{x^3 y^3 z^3}  = 3 x y z $, or directly by the identity:
$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3 xyz  = \frac12 (x+y+z)((x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2) \ge 0$.

Remark:
The obvious advantage of  such a procedure would be that one could determine lower bounds of the LHS by any term on the RHS or weighted sum of terms on the RHS, with weights between 0 and 1. In particular, these lower bounds could be chosen according to prior knowledge: if all $x_i$ are known to be roughly equal, the AM-GM bound is a good one. If the $x_i$ are known to differ much, one would choose other terms on the RHS as lower bound.

Comment: Here is a representation of AM-GM as a weighted sum of squares: $(2)$ in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.5055.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can.

We can do it by Bricks Throwing Method.

It's very ugly but it works.

For four variables we need to work with $(a+b+c+d)^4-256abcd$.

$3(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3(b+c+d)$ because we throw one brick:

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(3a^4-a^3(b+c+d))=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}(a^4-a^3b-ab^3+b^4)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}(a-b)^2(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

More brick trowing:

$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3(b+c+d)\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}a^2b^2$ gives

$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3(b+c+d)-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}a^2b^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}(a^3b-2a^2b^2+ab^3)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}ab(a-b)^2$ and so on...

I'll write a full proof.

More brick trowing:

$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}a^2b^2-\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2(bc+bd+cd)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{sym}(a-b)^2(c^2+d^2)$

The last brick trowing:

$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2(bc+bd+cd)-12abcd=\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{sym}(a-b)^2cd$.

After using these bricks throwing we'll write $(a+b+c+d)^4-256abcd$ like a sum of squares.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is "Bricks Throwing Method"?

Comment: @Martin R see my proof. I wrote a full proof for you.

Comment: @Michael: some reference to "Brick Throwing" would still be appreciated.

Comment: @Andreas it's just $(4,0,0)\succ(3,1,0)\succ(2,2,0)\succ(2,1,1)\succ(1,1,1,1)$, where all $\succ$ gives sum of squares. See my proof. The general is the same!

Comment: @Michael: ok I see it. Still I wonder where the term "brick throwing" is used or did you invent it? -- btw an inequality where the OP says that you pointed out it's still unsolved has been solved recently at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444352

Comment: @Andreas I know about words "brick throwing" 46 years at least. These words by one of my teachers. I think it's indeed  a bricks throwing. Take a column with four bricks. It's $(4,0,0)$. After  throwing of one brick we get $(3,1,0)$. This brick throwing gives $(4,0,0)\succ(3,1,0)$.

Comment: Perhaps you are talking about [Muirhead's Inequality](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Muirhead's_Inequality) ?

Comment: @Martin R No! I showed that at each step we can get sum of squares. Each step it's Muirhead, of course, but in Muirhead we are not interested  sum of squares.