# Prove this refinement of Nesbitt's inequality based on another

Tags: functions, derivatives, inequality, jensen-inequality, convexity-inequality

Let $a,b,c\in[1,2]$ such that $a,b$ are constants then prove  :

$$f(c)=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{b+a}\geq h(c)=(c-1)\frac{g(2)-g(1)}{2-1}+g(1)\geq g(c)=\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+bc+ca}}$$

Yes it's a probable refinement of HN_NH's inequality/ [Stronger than Nesbitt inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444352/stronger-than-nesbitt-inequality)

My refinement is based on two observations :

1. The function $g(c)$ is convex on $[1,2]$

2.The chord of a convex function is greater than the convex function.

To know if the LHS is good I have tried derivatives . It gives a quartic and it's very ugly so I can say that I have not the solution for the LHS but it seems to be true (numerical check).

### Update 12/11/2020:

The function :

$$p(c)=f(c)-h(c)$$

Is convex on $[1,2]$ so there is a possibility to use Jensen's inequality but now I don't see any good issue .

Using Jensen's inequality we have :

$$p(c)+p(1)\geq 2p\left(\frac{1+c}{2}\right)$$

And :

$$p\left(\frac{1+c}{2}\right)+p(1)\geq 2p\left(\frac{3+c}{4}\right)$$

And :

$$p\left(\frac{3+c}{4}\right)+p(1)\geq 2p\left(\frac{3+c}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

And so on...Playing with these inequalities we got the result I think !

Have you an idea to show the LHS(or confirm my update)?

Thanks in advance

Max.

Comment: @Andreas You solve the inequality I mention have you an idea to solve the LHS  here ? Thanks !

Comment: @RiverLi have you an idea to solve the LHS ?(I think this inequality is of interest )

Comment: What are $h(c)$ and $g(c)$?

Comment: @ErikSatie  I was not informed by your @. It is true. You may use software to verify it.

Comment: @CalvinLin $g(c)=\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+bc+ca}}$ and $h(c)=(c-1)\frac{g(2)-g(1)}{2-1}+g(1)$ .

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment, this inequality is true for all $a,b,c>0.$ By the way, the best inequality is:
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\sqrt{\frac94+{\frac {\sqrt {1158\sqrt {193}-3450}}{72}} \cdot \frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+bc+ca}}$$
I'm trying to prove your inequality. I will post it later.

Comment: Would you mind proving your inequality?