# Conjecture about :$\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\sqrt{\frac94+\frac32 \cdot \frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+bc+ca}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

It's a conjecture . I combine two inequalities : [Stronger than Nesbitt inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444352/stronger-than-nesbitt-inequality) and [Stronger than Nesbitt's inequality $\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281703/stronger-than-nesbitts-inequality-fraca-sqrt48b4c4-fracbac)

So now the conjecture :

Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a\geq b \geq c$ then we have :

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\sqrt{\frac94+\frac32 \cdot \frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+bc+ca}}$$

I cannot find any counter-example until now . To prove it I have tried the same method as here [Prove this refinement of Nesbitt's inequality based on another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903372/prove-this-refinement-of-nesbitts-inequality-based-on-another) without success .

My question :

Have you an element of proof or an counter-example ?

Thanks in advance !!

Max .

Comment: @RiverLi have you a counter-example or a proof ? Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe  Michael Rozenberg's shadow  have downvoted ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good reason that you can not prove:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\sqrt{\frac94+\frac32 \cdot \frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+bc+ca}}$$
It's wrong for $a=\frac53,b=1,c=\frac19.$
By the way, the following inequality is true:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\sqrt{\frac94+\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab+bc+ca}},$$
as verified by Bottema - Maple program.

Comment: Powerful Bottema!