# If $x,y,z>0$, prove that: $\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}\ge \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{7xyz}{(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, intuition, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x,y,z>0$, prove that: $\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}\ge \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{7xyz}{(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)}}$

The solution goes as follows:

$a=\frac{x}{y+z}$, $b=\frac{y}{z+x}$, $c=\frac{z}{x+y}$. We can see that:

$ab+bc+ac+2abc=1$

It's enough if: $(a+b+c)^2\ge 4-14abc$

$(a+b+c)^2\ge 4(ab+bc+ab+2abc)-14abc$

From Schur it is enough if: $6abc\ge\frac{9abc}{a+b+c}$ which is true from Nesbit.

Could you please provide a more intuitive and easier approach?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore could you please provide the SOS proof so that I can see it?

Comment: Michael sorry but rechecked my proof using SOS I  had made a calculation error so my proof is wrong ,anyway even if it was true it was very ugly ,Let me try to find another solution.I am sure Buffalo way will work but without computer the calculations can be very draining indeed .By the way I feel the substituition they used was intutive,

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore ok thank you very much for your time and effort, please when you find a nice solution, please share it as I am having difficulties understanding why someone would do what they did

Comment: So are you facing difficulty on how they got $ab+bc+ca+2abc=1$?there is anice proof for that

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore actually that's exactly what is giving me difficulties, I can't prove it

Comment: I'm also having difficulties in understanding why someone would initially think of that as being evident
could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore sorry for having deleted the chat, it's the first time I created a chat and I thought I had done something wrong. Sorry about that. Thank you so much for your response, your reasoning is brilliant, I have understood it implicitly.  Have a great day

Comment: @MichaelBlane We can get $a + b + c \ge \frac{3}{2}$ from $ab+bc+ac+2abc=1$ without using Nesbitt. Indeed, from $(a + b + c)^2 \ge 3(ab + bc + ca)$ and $a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$, we can easy get $a + b + c \ge \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: @Riverli can you provide the full derivation of the bound in an answer?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I think it is fine as comment. From $(a + b + c)^2 \ge 3(ab + bc + ca)$ and $a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$,
we have $\frac{(a + b + c)^2}{3} + 2 \cdot (\frac{a + b + c}{3})^3
\ge ab + bc + ca + 2abc = 1$ which results in $a + b + c \ge 3/2$.

Comment: @RiverLi Ah yes, you just solve $\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{2x^3}{27} - 1\geq 0$, thanks.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $x,y,z > 0 $, say $a = \frac{x}{y+z} ,  b=\frac{y}{x+z} , c=\frac{z}{x+y} $
then we'll proof that $$(a+b+c)^2 \ge 4 - 14\cdot a \cdot b \cdot c $$
$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+2.a.b+b^2+2.a.c+2.b.c+c^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2(a.b+b.c+a.c) $

as you said $a.b+a.c+b.c+2.a.b.c = 1$

$a^2+b^2+c^2 +2(1-2.a.b.c) \ge 4 - 14.a.b.c $

$ a^2+b^2+c^2 +2 - 4.a.b.c \ge 4 - 14.a.b.c $

$ a^2+b^2+c^2 +10.a.b.c   \ge 2 $

since $x,y,z > 0 $  means that $x$ or $y$ or $z$ are positive numbers, their lowest value is $ 0 + 10^{-n} $ and since our inequality speaks also minimum value, we can get the result by assuming the minimum value of $x,y,z$ there

for the simplest case scenario, this happens when $ x= y= z$ at the lowest level

$ x^2/(z+y)^2+y^2/(z+x)^2+z^2/(y+x)^2 + (10.x.y.z)/((y+x)(z+x)(z+y)) \ge 2 $

so if i say $x=y=z$, the result is $2$ this means that even if $x , y , z$ was $ < 0 $ our inequality would still be greater than 2

Answer (score 2):

**Version of 01.04.2021.**

Since the task is homogenious, one may denote
$$s=x+y+z=3,\quad r=xy+yz+zx,\quad p=xyz,\tag1$$
wherein
$$r\le\dfrac13s^2=3,\quad p\le\dfrac1{27}s^3=1. \tag2$$
At the same time,
$$p=(3-u)v,\quad r=(3-u)u+v,\tag3$$
where
$$u=x+y\in[0,3],\quad v=xy\in\left[0,\dfrac{u^2}4\right].\tag4$$

The given inequality takes the forms of
$$4\big(x(s-y)(s-z)+y(s-z)(s-x)+z(s-x)(s-y)\big)^2$$
$$ \ge \big(16(s-x)(s-y)(s-z)-56xyz\big)(s-x)(s-y)(s-z)$$
$$ = \big(4(s-x)(s-y)(s-z)-7xyz\big)^2 -49(xyz)^2,$$
or
$$4(s^3-2sr+3p)^2+49p^2\ge (4sr-11p)^2,\tag5$$
wherein, taking in accouint $(1)-(4),$

$$4(s^3-2sr+3p)^2+49p^2-(4sr-11p)^2$$
$$=4(27-6r+3p)^2+49p^2-(12r-11p)^2$$
$$=12(-108r+10pr-3p^2+54p+243)=12f(u,v),$$
$$f(u,v)=243-324u+108u^2+54v+36uv-60u^2v+10u^3v+3v^2+8uv^2-3u^2v^2,$$
$$f'_v(u,v)=54+36u-60u^2+10u^3+6v+16uv-6u^2v.$$
Then at the bounds by $\;v\;$

- $f(u,0)=27(3-2u)^2\ge0,$
- $f\left(u,\dfrac{u^2}4\right)=\dfrac3{16}(1296-1728u+648u^2+48u^3-79u^4+16u^5-u^6)$
  $=\dfrac3{16}(9-u^2)(u^2-8u+12)^2\ge0.$

At the stationary points
$$2f(u,v)=2f(u,v)-v\,f'_v(u,v)=g(u,v),$$
where

- $g(u,v)=486-648u+216u^2+(54+36u-60u^2+10u^3)v,$
- $g(u,0)=54(3-2u)^2\ge0,$
- $g\left(u,\dfrac{u^2}4\right)=\dfrac12(972-1296u+459u^2+18u^3-30u^4+5u^5)$
  $=\dfrac52\left(u+\dfrac{58}{15}\right)\left(u-\dfrac85\right)^2\left(u-\dfrac{10}3\right)^2 +\dfrac{253}{15}\left(u+3\right)\left(u-\dfrac53\right)^2$
  $+\dfrac1{1350}\left(95150-119630u+38207u^2\right)\ge0.$

Since $\;g(u,v)\;$ is a linear function by $\;v,\;$ it achives the least value at the edges of the area.

**Proved!**

Comment: Please check (1) for $a = 1, b = 1, c = 0$ (if $a, b, c > 0$, change a little bit).

Comment: @RiverLi This proposition does not correspond to the task standing.

Comment: $1 = ab + bc + ca + 2abc \ge 3(abc)^{2/3} + 2abc$ or $2p^3 + 3p^2 \le 1$ or $(p+1)^2(2p-1) \le 0$ or $p \le \frac{1}{2}$ or $abc \le \frac{1}{8}$, right?

Comment: @RiverLi stop oftopic,please!

Comment: Why offtopic? I think your solution is wrong. You said "$2p^3+3p^2-1=(p+1)^2(2p-1)\ge 0,\quad p\ge\dfrac12$", it should be $2p^3+3p^2-1 \le 0$. You make a mistake $2p^3+3p^2-1 \ge 0$.

Comment: @RiverLi You're right,thanks a lot. New proof is ready.

Comment: I think that you made a mistake $4(s^3-sr+3p)^2+49p^2\ge (4sr-11p)^2$. It should be $4(s^3- 2sr+3p)^2+49p^2\ge (4sr-11p)^2$. So your last step is incorrect.

Comment: How is this "neater" and "nicer" than the solution provided by OP?

Comment: @V.S.e.H.At least, used approach does not repeat OP proof. Besides, it contains new inequality for the classic symmetrical functions. At the same time, everybody has his own criteria of the soft terminologic things.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov  Check: $4p-5r=5xy(3-x-y)-4\big(xy+(x+y)(3-x-y)\big)$.

Comment: @RiverLi the typo fixed, thanks a lot!

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov $4p\ge 5r-11$ is incorrect, e.g., for $x = 0, y = z = 3/2$. Or $x = 1/100, y = z = 299/200$.

Comment: @RiverLi Looks correct. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Sorry, it is still incorrect.
$4(27-6r+3p)^2+49p^2-(12r-11p)^2
= 12(-3p^2+10pr+54p-108r+243)$ is wrong. E.g., for $x = y = z = 1$ (so $s = 3, r = 3, p = 1$),
we have $4(27-6r+3p)^2+49p^2-(12r-11p)^2 = 0$, however,
$12(-3p^2+10pr+54p-108r+243) = 576$.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Do you agree my last comment? I think you answer is incorrect. You may edit it or delete it. It is not good for a wrong answer to get a bounty. I think that it is good for you to edit it or delete it. By the way, I did not downvote you.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you for the support! Fixed and verified.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Nice. I will check it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's an attempt to delete the square root .

My only idea is to use Bernoulli's inequality and play with the coefficient $\sqrt{2}$.We have :

$$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\frac{7xyz}{(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)}}\leq \sqrt{\alpha}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{4}{\alpha}-1-\frac{14}{\alpha}\frac{xyz}{(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)}\Big)\Big)$$

Remains to show (using the OP's substitution) when:

$$ \sqrt{\alpha}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{4}{\alpha}-1-\frac{14}{\alpha}abc\Big)\Big)\leq a+b+c$$

Wich seems to be easier I think.

The last inequality is equivalent to :

$$\frac{y}{2}+\frac{2}{y}\leq a+b+c+\frac{7}{y}abc$$

With $y^2=\alpha$ so now a bit of algebra to get :

$$y^2+4\leq 2y(a+b+c)+14abc$$

Now putting $y=a+b+c$ we get the inequality of the OP.

The end is the same as the OP.

Comment: @RiverLi Good point but If you read carefully I say that it works only for some values.

Comment: @RiverLi Well there is a typo !

Comment: @RiverLi Well you're right I forgot that and maybe it's a bad idea .But I don't see better than the OP's proof !

Comment: @RiverLi I think there is something wrong can you tell me where ?

Comment: @RiverLi So do you think it's a nice refinement ?

Comment: @RiverLi Hum the end is the same as the OP  should I add a sentence ?

Comment: Sorry, I see. You just eliminate the root sign by a different manner?

Comment: @RiverLi When I understood that I found it very funny !I'm totally agree it's just a shame because we cannot find another simple proof without fall in the triviality.Lol have a great day Dear River.

Comment: @ Erik Satie: Because the OP's proof is nice except that Nesbitt is not necessary.

Comment: @RiverLi I think we can show a part of the inequality https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444352/stronger-than-nesbitt-inequality .Agree ?

Comment: Do you have better solution?