# Conjecture-refinement related to Nesbitt's inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, uvw

Prove or disprove : $ a\geq b\geq c\geq 1$:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}\geq\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+\frac{9}{4}\frac{(c^4+a^4+b^4-c^2a^2-b^2a^2-c^2b^2)}{(3(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}})(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}+\frac{(c^2+a^2+b^2-ca-ba-cb)(a+b+c)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}$$

Motivation :

As linked in the comment for @Albus Dumbledore it's an attempt to make the HN_NH's problem more symmetric and use $uvw's$ method .Again it's not a messy result because I have spend some hours to find it .

First we remark that the inequality is homogenous and we can try the substitution $3u=a+b+c$, $3v^2=ab+bc+ca$ and $w^3=abc$ and apply the uvw's method .

We have :
$$a^4+b^4+c^4=(9u^2-6v^2)^2-2(9v^4-6uw^3)$$
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2=9v^4-6uw^3$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=9u^2-6v^2$$

And :
$\left(\frac{((3u)((3u)^2-4(3v^2))+5w^3)}{3u3v^2-w^3}+2\right)^2\geq \frac{9}{4}+\frac{(9/4)((9u^2-6v^2)^2-2(9v^4-6uw^3)-(9v^4-6uw^3))+3w(9u^2-9v^2)(3u)}{(3w)(3u3v^2-w^3)}$

it's enough to find an extreme value of our expression for the extreme value of $w^3$ wich happens for an equality case of two variables .

Since the last inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $b=c=1$.

$$\frac{2}{a+1}+\frac{a}{2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+\frac{9}{4}\frac{(a^4+1-2a^2)}{(3(a)^{\frac{1}{3}})(a+1)^2(2)}+\frac{(a^2+1-2a)(a+2)}{(a+1)^2(2)}}$$

Now it seems to be clear : we get a long polynomial with a root equal to one . See [the factorization by Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20%28%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Ba%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7B2%7D%29%5E2-%28%5Cfrac%7B9%7D%7B4%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B9%7D%7B4%7D%5Cfrac%7B%28a%5E4%2B1-2a%5E2%29%7D%7B%283%28a%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D%29%28a%2B1%29%5E2%282%29%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B%28a%5E2%2B1-2a%29%28a%2B2%29%7D%7B%28a%2B1%29%5E2%282%29%7D%29)

But I think that it misses something in my proof.

If there is a mistake feel free to comment.

Is my proof correct ?
How to show it  with another method?

Ps:One downvote a day, keeps the truth away.

PPS:Don't forget the constraint above !

Comment: Is there *any* motivation to prove  this  messy inequality or is it just something you conjunctured out of thin air! ? :)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444352/stronger-than-nesbitt-inequality .

Comment: Where  is your [previous bounty award +100](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4064256/prove-fracabc-fracbac-fraccab-geq-sqrt-frac94-frac3/4081741#4081741)?

Comment: I have not vote there

Comment: If you use the identity $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b} = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}+\frac{(a-c)^2}{(a+b)(b+c)}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{(a+b)(a+c)}\right)$, and then square it, you may make some progress.

Comment: @Blitzer I was not aware of it thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Having spent more time than I should trying to prove this, I think it is not true.
For example take $a=2, b=2, c=1$.
I think we get
$$LHS = 1.58333$$
$$RHS=1.58335$$